# How to describe specific attributes of EC2 instances in AWS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

For example, I want to describe only 4 attributes of my EC2 instances.  Like a SQL projection.

**This is how I'm describing my EC2 instances:**

```
  var settings = { apiVersion: '2017-01-01', region: process.env.AWS_REGION };
  var ec2 = new AWS.EC2(settings);
  var params = {
      DryRun: false,
      Filters: []
  };

  params.Filters.push({...});

  ec2.describeInstances(params, function(err, data) {
    ....
  });
```

The `data` object returns a list of reservation objects.  That reservation object has an attribute called `Instances` and every object within that array looks as follow:

```
  { 
    AmiLaunchIndex: 0,
    ImageId: 'ami-00000',
    InstanceId: 'i-00000',
    InstanceType: 't2.micro',
    KeyName: 'KP',
    LaunchTime: 2018-01-14T21:36:36.000Z,
    Monitoring: [Object],
    Placement: [Object],
    PrivateDnsName: 'ip-0000000',
    PrivateIpAddress: '172.0.0.0',
    ProductCodes: [],
    PublicDnsName: '',
    State: [Object],
    StateTransitionReason: 'User initiated (2018-01-14 21:49:51 GMT)',
    SubnetId: 'subnet-000000',
    VpcId: 'vpc-00000',
    Architecture: 'x86_64',
    BlockDeviceMappings: [Object],
    ClientToken: 'vpyw000000',
    EbsOptimized: false,
    EnaSupport: true,
    Hypervisor: 'xen',
    IamInstanceProfile: [Object],
    ElasticGpuAssociations: [],
    NetworkInterfaces: [Object],
    RootDeviceName: '/dev/sda1',
    RootDeviceType: 'ebs',
    SecurityGroups: [Object],
    SourceDestCheck: true,
    StateReason: [Object],
    Tags: [Object],
    VirtualizationType: 'hvm'
  }
```

**So, How can I describe specific attributes of my EC2 instances? Is it that possible?**

Comment: I don't believe that you can do this with the API, but it should be possible to destructure the response to get just the 4 attributes you need.

Comment: @jarmod definitely I can do that, but I want to avoid the transfer of that huge amount of data.  I think it is not possible to get only a few attributes.

Comment: Agree that GraphQL-style support would be nice so that you can request just the attributes of interest.